# shape of Conv2d in multiclass text classification

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am doing multi class text classification with Convolutional neural network, I applied the below code on my glove embedding weights, I got good result but I have a question about CONV2D shape:
why in CONV2D 1 we get conv_1 (None, 407, 1, 64) and respectively in conv_2 :None, 406, 1, 64) and in conv_2 :405 ?

```
               


Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_18 (InputLayer)           (None, 409)          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_17 (Embedding)        (None, 409, 100)     1766600     input_18[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_10 (Reshape)            (None, 409, 100, 1)  0           embedding_17[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_1 (Conv2D)                 (None, 407, 1, 64)   19264       reshape_10[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_2 (Conv2D)                 (None, 406, 1, 64)   25664       reshape_10[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_3 (Conv2D)                 (None, 405, 1, 64)   32064       reshape_10[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_16 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 1, 1, 64)     0           conv_1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_17 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 1, 1, 64)     0           conv_2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_18 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 1, 1, 64)     0           conv_3[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_6 (Concatenate)     (None, 3, 1, 64)     0           max_pooling2d_16[0][0]           
                                                                 max_pooling2d_17[0][0]           
                                                                 max_pooling2d_18[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)             (None, 192)          0           concatenate_6[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_11 (Dropout)            (None, 192)          0           flatten_5[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)                (None, 3)            579         dropout_11[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,844,171
Trainable params: 1,844,171
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Embedding
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Embedding, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout,concatenate
from keras.layers.core import Reshape, Flatten
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Model
from keras import regularizers

sequence_length = 409
filter_sizes = [3,4,5]
num_filters = 64
drop = 0.5
EMBEDDING_DIM=100


embedding_layer = Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            trainable=True)


inputs = Input(shape=(sequence_length,))
embedding = embedding_layer(inputs)
reshape = Reshape((sequence_length,EMBEDDING_DIM,1))(embedding)

conv_0 = Conv2D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[0], EMBEDDING_DIM),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),name='conv_1')(reshape)
conv_1 = Conv2D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[1], EMBEDDING_DIM),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),name='conv_2')(reshape)
conv_2 = Conv2D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[2], EMBEDDING_DIM),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),name='conv_3')(reshape)

maxpool_0 = MaxPooling2D((sequence_length - filter_sizes[0] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1))(conv_0)
maxpool_1 = MaxPooling2D((sequence_length - filter_sizes[1] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1))(conv_1)
maxpool_2 = MaxPooling2D((sequence_length - filter_sizes[2] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1))(conv_2)

merged_tensor = concatenate([maxpool_0, maxpool_1, maxpool_2], axis=1)
flatten = Flatten()(merged_tensor)
reshape = Reshape((3*num_filters,))(flatten)
dropout = Dropout(drop)(flatten)
output = Dense(units=3, activation='softmax',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(dropout)

# this creates a model that includes
model = Model(inputs, output)
adam = Adam(lr=1e-3)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['acc'])
print(model.summary())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nothing to be worried about. That's a basic issue with any convolution operation with kernels. The size of the kernels convolving over an image will cause a few pixels to be left out. Here is a [link](https://d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-neural-networks/padding-and-strides.html) describing the issue in more detail.

Assuming that the input shape is `ℎ×` and the convolution kernel shape is `ℎ×`, then the output shape will be `(ℎ−ℎ+1)×(−+1)`

[image]

One way to handle this is by setting the `padding` parameter in the layer as `'same'`.

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='same', data_format=None,
    dilation_rate=(1, 1), groups=1, activation=None, use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros',
    kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, **kwargs
)
```

**With padding = 'valid'**

```
> input_shape = (4, 28, 28, 3)
> x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
> y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
> print(y.shape)
(4, 26, 26, 3)
```

**With padding = 'same'**

```
> input_shape = (4, 28, 28, 3)
> x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
> y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', padding="same", input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
> print(y.shape)
(4, 28, 28, 3)
```

---

**EDIT:** You are better off using conv1d for text / temporal data, instead of the multiple reshapes to use conv2d. Here is your model architecture with 1D convolutions.

I am not sure why you are doing what you are doing for the maxpooling layers though. I have basically tried to keep the same forward computation but you should look at those layers and see if they make sense.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, regularizers

vocab_size = 1000

inp = layers.Input(shape=(409,))
emb = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 100)(inp)
conv1 = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, padding='same')(emb)
conv2 = layers.Conv1D(64, 4, padding='same')(emb)
conv3 = layers.Conv1D(64, 5, padding='same')(emb)

max1 = layers.MaxPool1D(409, strides=1)(conv1)
max2 = layers.MaxPool1D(409, strides=1)(conv2)
max3 = layers.MaxPool1D(409, strides=1)(conv3)

conc = layers.concatenate([max1, max2, max3])
flat = layers.Flatten()(conc)
drop = layers.Dropout(0.5)(flat)
out = layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer='l2')(drop)

model = Model(inp,out)
model.summary()
```

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_21 (InputLayer)           [(None, 409)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_20 (Embedding)        (None, 409, 100)     100000      input_21[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_50 (Conv1D)              (None, 409, 64)      19264       embedding_20[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_51 (Conv1D)              (None, 409, 64)      25664       embedding_20[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_52 (Conv1D)              (None, 409, 64)      32064       embedding_20[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_39 (MaxPooling1D) (None, 1, 64)        0           conv1d_50[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_40 (MaxPooling1D) (None, 1, 64)        0           conv1d_51[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_41 (MaxPooling1D) (None, 1, 64)        0           conv1d_52[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_11 (Concatenate)    (None, 1, 192)       0           max_pooling1d_39[0][0]           
                                                                 max_pooling1d_40[0][0]           
                                                                 max_pooling1d_41[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)             (None, 192)          0           concatenate_11[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 192)          0           flatten_5[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 3)            579         dropout_4[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 177,571
Trainable params: 177,571
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: thanks when I add padding="same ", the error: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: Doesn't matter if text or image, it's just a natural thing that happens with convolutions. Also, I see that you are using conv2d but still convolving on a single dimension. Why not just use conv1d? Thts what is generally used with text classification.

Comment: Also, the issue that you are facing is more to do with the slightly weird kernel shape being used here.\

Comment: Instead of reshaping and adding a new dimension, just use conv1d. That would convolve over the embedding similar to what you are currently doing.

Comment: thank you very much can you help me how to implement it? I am new to python and cnn..